# jQuery improve select all checkboxes function

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a checkall script that select all checkboxes via a checkbox click.
Currently it works great but I need multiple instances of it in the same form. So I need to modify it to only target the closest fieldset.

Here is the working code, also here is the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/22w3B/

```
    $('.checkall').click(function () {
    var checked = $(this).data('checked');
    $('fieldset').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', !checked);
    $(this).data('checked', !checked);
});
```

And here is my failed attempt:

```
    $('.checkall').click(function () {
    var checked = $(this).data('checked');
    var next_set = $('fieldset').next();
    $(next_set).find(':checkbox').attr('checked', !checked);
    $(this).data('checked', !checked);
});
```

Comment: Can't you give each fieldset a different ID or class, then just use $('#fieldsetID :checkbox')

Comment: Hi, I could but I'm trying to avoid having to create a different function for each fieldset because this is going to be a long page. Cheers

Comment: It's better to bind to the change event on checkboxes - the click event fires before the checkbox gets checked, so you have to invert the value before you use it.  It gets confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a one line change from your original attempt.

```
$('.checkall').click(function () {
    var checked = $(this).data('checked');
    $(this).parents('li').next().find(':checkbox').attr('checked', !checked);
    $(this).data('checked', !checked);
});
```

But why not just give the fieldsets their own IDs to make it a lot less fragile?

Comment: Thanks that great! I'm not keen on giving IDs because I don't want to create a new function for each fieldset. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the "closest()" function in JQUERY?

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

Getting the closest fieldset with `.parents("li").next("fieldset")` and setting it's checked attribute to "checked":

```
$(".checkall").click(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']",
        $(this).parents("li")
               .next("fieldset"))
    .attr("checked","checked");
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that but it didn't work, strange because this looks like the right solution. Cheers

Comment: Oh, I didn't check the DOM before writing this script, It's better using `parents("li").next("fieldset")` instead of `closest("fieldset")`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, but IMO the easiest is to move the "select all" checkboxes into the fieldsets, then:

```
$('.select-all').change(function() {
  var new_value = this.checked;
  $(this).closest('fieldset').find('input:checkbox').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('select-all')) {
      this.checked = new_value;
    }
  });
});
```